# Automatic number formating in a table

Tags: tables, format

How can I apply the "\num{}" formatting to all numbers in a table without retyping the command each time? I am using Arial font, so the numbers look different compared to when I use the \num{} command

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l l l}
         \toprule
         Parameter & Grösse & Einheit \\
         \midrule
         $\varnothing$ Querkraftbewehrung & \num{12} & [\unit{mm}] \\
         $\varnothing$ Verstärkungsstab & 28 & [\unit{mm}] \\
         \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an `S` column (from the siunitx package) to apply it to the whole column:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=2.0] l}
         \toprule
         Parameter & {Grösse} & Einheit \\
         \midrule
         $\varnothing$ Querkraftbewehrung & 12 & \unit{mm} \\
         $\varnothing$ Verstärkungsstab & 28 & \unit{mm} \\
         \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. :-)  I'd recommend adding the option `detect-mode`, so that the numbers use the text font (Arial) rather than tha math font. BTW, no need to load the `fontenc` package when using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico I agree that the mixture of cmr and arial looks strange, but as far as I understand the question, that's why they use `\num`.

Comment: I somehow doubt that this is why the OP is using `\num`... However, I may be wrong.

Comment: @Mico If they wanted arial numbers, why would they use `\num{...}`? They'd get arial numbers "for free" by doing nothing.

Comment: @Mico But thanks for spotting the fontenc package, I completely overlooked it amongst the other packages.